# min-height for a div with "display: table" not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have given a min-height to a div with display property as table for rendering the inner text vertically center.The min-height given is not working with Firefox browser.

I have put the code in a fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvbphases/s1p6mq96/)

```
<div class="readmore_box">
    <div class="readmore_box_main">
        <p>State of the Market Address: Update on developments in the global stone industry</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box_bottom">
         <h4>more Info</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Pete min-height is there with ".readmore_box_main " class. but height property seems working fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a Firefox bug

see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866

`min-height` won't work with `display: table`

You need to use fixed height for solving this.